# Customisation of BizTalk BTDF MSI Files

Tags: wix, windows-installer, biztalk, btdf

Is there a way via the BTDF configuration files to customize the Program Group, default installation folder and other high-level installer settings for a BizTalk BTDF generated MSI file?  This would be in the latest BTDF version.

As BTDF is built on Wix I'm wondering if there is any way to access these kind of settings, or alternatively whether any of them are exposed in the .btdfproj file (though searching the documentation and online resources has drawn a blank here - apologies if I missed anything obvious).

The situation is that we will be deploying over 200 interfaces to the same server, and the default approach will become hard to manage.  I'm aware that I could post-process the MSIs but would rather avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can get the `GenericBizTalk.wsx` file from the `%PROGRAM_FILES%\Deployment Framework for BizTalk x.x\Developer\GenericBizTalkMSI.wxs` as a starting point.  Add it to your solution, and update/customize it as desired.  Then, set the property in your `.btdfproj`:

```
<WixProjectFile>MyNewGreatWix.wxs</WixProjectFile>
```

See here for more info: http://www.tfabraham.com/BTDFDocs/V5_5/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkDocs.html?CustomizingtheDefaultWiXTemplate.html (applies to current version as well).